# Mocha Does Not Run Second describe()

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I am writing a test coverage for my code base and just started using Mocha/Chai for my backend. For whatever reason I can't get my second describe() to run in this function. I don't receive any error, it just exits after running the first describe() suite.

```js
export async function testCreateUnknownCustomer(billCodeTest) {
  let unknownRecordTest;
  describe("Create A Unknown Customer Record", function () {
    it("Creates a new unknown customer", async function () {
      unknownRecordTest = await CustomersController.createUnknownCustomer(
        '+15555551111',
        billCodeTest
      )
    })
    it('Should Be a Instance of a Sequelize Model', function () {
      expect(unknownRecordTest instanceof Model).equals(true);
    })
  });

  describe("Hard Delete unknown customer record", function () {
    const unknownID = unknownRecordTest.customer_id;
    it("Deletes a customer record", async function () {
      console.log(await unknownRecordTest.destroy());
      console.log(unknownRecordTest);
    }) 
  });
}
```

Comment: How did you use `testCreateUnknownCustomer`? Show more code and debug details

Comment: It is executed from a main.test.mjs file that imports the function and runs it. My package.json test script is set to: "test": "NODE_ENV=devTest mocha --recursive --exit -r dotenv-flow/config test/main.test.mjs"

Unfortunately the console is light on debug details and basically tells me everything succeeded up to the Create A Unknown Customer Record, after which it just skips the "Hard Delete Unknown Customer Record" suite.

Comment: `DEBUG='mocha*' mocha` will give you more detail of what mocha is doing.

Comment: I also want to say that you can only have 1 top level `describe` per file, but as slideshowp2 if you can show more detail of your setup, your are loading the tests in a slightly different way to normal

Comment: @Matt I also tried nesting the second `describe` but it didn't yield any different results. I'm not sure what else I can show you from, my setup? I can tell you the context of trying to run a serialized list of tests from a main.test.js file was to try and automate the testing of user records on-boarding in various different contexts. I was trying to start with small incremental unit test that build up to a certain user state and then try variations of actions in that user state.

Comment: multiple top level describes were fine in plain mocha test files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving the `describes` raw in the file seems to have fixed everything. As opposed to wrapping it in a function that is exported and run in a `main.test.js` execution file. I don't really have a technical explanation why secondary describes wouldn't have executed regardless.